# Is there any alternative for "onDomRefresh" event (in Marionette) in backbone js?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, marionette

Marionette js has a "onDomRefresh" event which can be used after the view has been rendered. 
I'm looking for something in Backbone which can be used as a alternative to "onDomRefresh" since I don't use marionette.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to implement a jQuery slider on the backbone view. So need to initialize it right after the view is rendered.

Comment: Are you not in control of the view rendering?
Can you change the `render()` to include your slider initialization?

Comment: I had included the slider initialization in the render, but it doesn't works the first time the view is rendered. But works on subsequent renders.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery/javascript function to bind your to function to document/window before unload event

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      //any;
});
```